# Maximum threshold for field value in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Is it any function in mongodb to inc field's value with maximum threshold? For example I need to inc money value but I don't want the field value is greater than 100000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$min` operator in Aggregation pipeline. The first parameter can be the increased amount, and the second can be the maximum amount allowed.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "key": 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "amount": {
        "$min": [
          {
            "$sum": [
              "$amount",  // Current value
              500  // Amount to increase
            ]
          },
          100000  // Maximum threshold
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/N-SN1267l1M